# RedHat Memory Used High

Tags: memory, virtual-machine, redhat

Looking for some help if you will..

I have a virtual machine on RedHat 6.5 with 32gb memory.
A free is showing 24.6gb used, 8.2gb free. Only 418mb is cached, 1.8gb buffers.

Executed a top and sorted by virtual used, and I can only account for about 6gb of that 24.6gb used.
A "ps aux" doesn't show any processes that could be taking the memory.

I am flummoxed and looking for some advice on where I can look to see whats taking the memory?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: As I said, only 418mb is cached, 1.8gb buffers.
So 32gb total ram, 24.6 is reported to be used. With just over 2.2gb of that in buffers/cache

Comment: check the output of "ps aux | sort -nk +4 | tail"

Answer (score 0):

Below Bash Script will help you figure out which application is consuming how much of memory.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Make sure only root can run our script

if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
exit 1
fi

### Functions
#This function will count memory statistic for passed PID
get_process_mem ()
{
PID=$1
#we need to check if 2 files exist
if [ -f /proc/$PID/status ];
then
if [ -f /proc/$PID/smaps ];
then
#here we count memory usage, Pss, Private and Shared = Pss-Private
Pss=`cat /proc/$PID/smaps | grep -e "^Pss:" | awk '{print $2}'| paste -sd+ | bc `
Private=`cat /proc/$PID/smaps | grep -e "^Private" | awk '{print $2}'| paste -sd+ | bc `
#we need to be sure that we count Pss and Private memory, to avoid errors
if [ x"$Rss" != "x" -o x"$Private" != "x" ];
then

let Shared=${Pss}-${Private}
Name=`cat /proc/$PID/status | grep -e "^Name:" |cut -d':' -f2`
#we keep all results in bytes
let Shared=${Shared}*1024
let Private=${Private}*1024
let Sum=${Shared}+${Private}

echo -e "$Private + $Shared = $Sum \t $Name"
fi
fi
fi
}

#this function make conversion from bytes to Kb or Mb or Gb
convert()
{
value=$1
power=0
#if value 0, we make it like 0.00
if [ "$value" = "0" ];
then
value="0.00"
fi

#We make conversion till value bigger than 1024, and if yes we divide by 1024
while [ $(echo "${value} > 1024"|bc) -eq 1 ]
do
value=$(echo "scale=2;${value}/1024" |bc)
let power=$power+1
done

#this part get b,kb,mb or gb according to number of divisions
case $power in
0) reg=b;;
1) reg=kb;;
2) reg=mb;;
3) reg=gb;;
esac

echo -n "${value} ${reg} "
}

#to ensure that temp files not exist
[[ -f /tmp/res ]] && rm -f /tmp/res
[[ -f /tmp/res2 ]] && rm -f /tmp/res2
[[ -f /tmp/res3 ]] && rm -f /tmp/res3

#if argument passed script will show statistic only for that pid, of not – we list all processes in /proc/ #and get statistic for all of them, all result we store in file /tmp/res
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
pids=`ls /proc | grep -e [0-9] | grep -v [A-Za-z] `
for i in $pids
do
get_process_mem $i >> /tmp/res
done
else
get_process_mem $1>> /tmp/res
fi

#This will sort result by memory usage
cat /tmp/res | sort -gr -k 5 > /tmp/res2

#this part will get uniq names from process list, and we will add all lines with same process list
#we will count nomber of processes with same name, so if more that 1 process where will be
# process(2) in output
for Name in `cat /tmp/res2 | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq`
do
count=`cat /tmp/res2 | awk -v src=$Name '{if ($6==src) {print $6}}'|wc -l| awk '{print $1}'`
if [ $count = "1" ];
then
count=""
else
count="(${count})"
fi

VmSizeKB=`cat /tmp/res2 | awk -v src=$Name '{if ($6==src) {print $1}}' | paste -sd+ | bc`
VmRssKB=`cat /tmp/res2 | awk -v src=$Name '{if ($6==src) {print $3}}' |   paste -sd+ | bc`
total=`cat /tmp/res2 | awk '{print $5}' | paste -sd+ | bc`
Sum=`echo "${VmRssKB}+${VmSizeKB}"|bc`
#all result stored in /tmp/res3 file
echo -e "$VmSizeKB + $VmRssKB = $Sum \t ${Name}${count}" >>/tmp/res3
done

#this make sort once more.
cat /tmp/res3 | sort -gr -k 5 | uniq > /tmp/res

#now we print result , first header
echo -e "Private \t + \t Shared \t = \t RAM used \t Program"
#after we read line by line of temp file
while read line
do
echo $line | while read a b c d e f
do
#we print all processes if Ram used if not 0
if [ $e != "0" ]; then
#here we use function that make conversion
echo -en "`convert $a` \t $b \t `convert $c` \t $d \t `convert $e` \t $f"
echo ""
fi
done
done < /tmp/res #this part print footer, with counted Ram usage echo "--------------------------------------------------------" echo -e "\t\t\t\t\t\t `convert $total`" echo "========================================================" # we clean temporary file [[ -f /tmp/res ]] && rm -f /tmp/res [[ -f /tmp/res2 ]] && rm -f /tmp/res2 [[ -f /tmp/res3 ]] && rm -f /tmp/res3
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a wild stab at this. Without having access to the machine or additional information troubleshooting this will be difficult.

The /tmp file system is special in that it exists entirely in memory. There are a couple others that are like this but /tmp is a special flower. Check the disk usage on this directory and you may see where your memory is getting consumed. ( du -sh /tmp )